# Woocommerce Single Product Page Customzation

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

[See Full Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uvyrx.png)
[image: a busy cat]

I would like to use this red marked area

I have tried few plugins, also some css but it's not working
Is it possible  to increase image div size and move texts towards right?

Note:
No Side bar template is used

You can check page with this link: http://demo.challengershub.com/product/mount-everest/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can change the column width containing the image and description.

In CSS add the code below, the first block is for the image column and the second is for the content column. You can, of course, change the percentages to better fit what you're looking for.

```
.woocommerce #content div.product div.images, .woocommerce div.product div.images, .woocommerce-page #content div.product div.images, .woocommerce-page div.product div.images {
    width: 70%;
}

.woocommerce #content div.product div.summary, .woocommerce div.product div.summary, .woocommerce-page #content div.product div.summary, .woocommerce-page div.product div.summary {
    width: 28%;
}
```

Comment: It's working perfectly fine, thanks allot. Much Appreciated.

Comment: But it't no more Responsive in mobile

Can you please help me to fix this
, Screenshot:
https://imgur.com/gallery/SSn19Cw